# Passing in an array of strings with unique variable names associated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How could I pass in an array of strings for 'name' so I can consolidate these useWatch calls into one?

```
const nameValue = useWatch({name: 'name'});
const descriptionValue = useWatch({name: 'description'});
const categoryValue = useWatch({name: 'category'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question. I believe you'd need to refactor "useWatch" as well, but here's a simple idea:

```
const [nameValue, descriptionvalue, categoryValue] = useWatch(['name', 'description', 'category');
```

The idea here is that you'll destructure the return value of your useWatch hook. You'll also initialize it by passing an array of names.

Comment: I would still need the name key in the object that's being passed into useWatch tough.

Comment: Well, the name is the string itself. Like I said, You'll need to refactor something :P You could also pass an array of objects, if you insist on having the name key: `[{name: 'name'}, {name: 'description'}]`